# Sharing session (or cookie) using Grails acegi plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security

Is it possible for two different Grails project, also having different domains, to share a session/cookie?

Let's say I have 2 sites: www.mycompany.com, and, www.othercompany.com. Assume that both sites are having same domains, and same database and records too. What I want to know is if this code:

```
authenticateService.userDomain()
```

or even the

```
authenticateService.isLoggedIn()
```

will behave and return exactly the same object/result whether it is called in either of the site.

Basically, what we need is a solution for sharing/identifying logged in user between two different sites. Need more details on how to implement this using acegi 0.5.2 and grails 1.2.1.

Hoping for any leads on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding cross-domain authentication the only thing that comes into my mind is using a single-sign-on service. There are a few open-source SSO implementations available, among them:

- [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas)
- [OpenSSO](https://opensso.dev.java.net/)
- [Josso](http://www.josso.org)
- Tomcat also has a [SingleSingOn valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/host.html)

This list is by far not complete. Speaking of CAS it definitly works with Grails and Acegi.